# audio issues: VLC play a video with no sound and YouTube shows an error

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10, windows-explorer

So I upgraded to Windows 10 a while ago and I am still in the process of solving various issues. One odd thing I noticed is that if I try to restart explorer, it only brings up a file explorer window. Shouldn't it restart the Desktop as well? The bar at the bottom shows up, but when I put my mouse over it, I get the blue loading circle. The only thing on the Taskbar you can see is the windows key and search option which doesn't work because of the loading circle. My desktop is black. I also have to manually adjust screen brightness and volume by going to the control panel when this happens. Using my keyboard buttons for it doesn't work at all. Otherwise, my computer is fully functional by use of task manager and Alt+Tab. Any ideas on how to fix it? I could just restart my computer, but I rather solve the issue, so I won't have to restart my computer.

Using this DOES NOT help:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe   
start explorer.exe   
exit
```

I've tried almost every possible way of opening explorer.exe, but nothing works.

Note: I restarted explorer because I was having audio issues. The audio stopped working. I got it to work after restating `audiodg`. However, the explorer issue happens with or without audio. I am not sure if this has anything to do with my issue, but I am just putting it out there.

Update: I know now that this is related to my audio issue since it only happens when my audio crashes. Videos will work depending on the website/program.

For example, VLC will play a video with no sound, but Youtube gives me:

> If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device.

Comment: If its been less then 30 days since you upgraded I strongly rolling back the installation to your previous version of Windows.  It sounds like you have major system corruption based on the behavior you describe.

Comment: I don't think I need to take it that far. It works well most of the time. It is just when I need to restart explorer.  This isn't an issue I have often. The audio issue happens more often than this.

Comment: Killing Windows explorer then starting it, should restart explorer, if all you get is a windows explorer window there is something serious wrong.

Comment: So I have an update. My explorer problem IS related to the audio problem I have been having. I recently updated windows and tried restarting explorer out of curiosity. It worked, so I thought it was fixed. However, my audio stopped working just now and when I tried restarting explorer.exe, the same issue occurred with the black screen.

Answer (score 0):

If VLC plays a video with no sound (and you've it on), then either:

- it's a problem with your video audio codec (reinstall VLC or [codecs](http://www.vlccodec.com/)),
- it's a problem with you sound drives; if so, reinstall them, upgrade or revert to stable once.

If YouTube fails with:

> If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device.

you need to should:

- check for HTML5 compatibility issues,
- try restarting your browser,
- try different browser (e.g. Brave, Firefox, Waterfox, Epic, Opera, Safari, etc),
- force browser to fallback to flash video playing,
- reinstall/upgrade your Flash plugins,
- try different sites such as Vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found an article that shows how to reset the Windows 10 audio services.  This helps somewhat
(Follow step #2 shown here)
https://www.techbout.com/audio-services-not-responding-in-windows-10-40286/

In my case I am using VLC media player to play a DVD from an externally plugged in DVD player.  After a few minutes, the Windows 10 Audio services module crashes and my PC cannot play sound any more.  This gets the sound to start back up, but the sound crashes again soon after.  Still this is better than the sound being completely off, and gets the sound to restart after a bit.